# How to get list of documents and not listen for changes in flutter cloud firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My application is again fetching list of items from firestore whenever I make a sort locally.

Due to which I am losing my sorted list and getting the original list back again.

Essentially, I am looking for a .once() alternative as I used in firebase realtime db with JS.

```
fetchItemsFromDb().then((itemsFromDb) {
      setState(() {
        items = itemsFromDb;
        isProcessed = true;
      });
});

fetchItemsFromDb() async {
  List<Item> items = [];
  await Firestore.instance.collection('items').getDocuments().then((data) {
    items = data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot item) {
      var i = item.data;
      return Item(
        i['itemName'],
        int.parse(i['quantity']),
        int.parse(i['price']),
        i['veg'],
        i['uid'],
        i['timestamp'],
        LatLng(i['location'].latitude, i['location'].longitude),
      );
    }).toList();
  });

  return items;
}
```

Comment: `getDocuments()` work similar to `once()`. They both fetch data a single time, so I don't understand the issue here.

Comment: Hey Doug, strange thing is that whatever changes I am doing through firestore web console is reflecting in my list view. I believe thats not a desired behaviour for once.

Comment: It's also not the behavior of getDocuments().  Something else is wrong.  You'll have to debug your app and figure out what is calling fetchItemsFromDb repeatedly, if this is the only code you have that queries.

Comment: I totally get that,   can it somehow be related to the fact that documents being mapped to items list directly there by set state function, where items is a state and any change in origin is syncing with state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FetchItemsFromDB() should be working how you expect it to, it could be that the code calling the function:

```
fetchItemsFromDb().then((itemsFromDb) {
      setState(() {
        items = itemsFromDb;
        isProcessed = true;
      });
});
```

is being run again when you do not expect it. Does that code live in a build method? If so it will run anytime the widget it is in rebuilds, which depending on how you are doing your local sort may be happening. If you only need it to run once maybe add it to the initState() function for the widget.